# Learning from Linux log files

Tags: linux, perl, file, linux-kernel, logging

I was wondering about the utility of storing metadata (Abbreviation Expansion, Brief Message, links to online resources) associated with messages, in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` etc.

For instance, for a message like `ACPI: Processor [CPU1] (supports 8 throttling states)` I would search online about CPU throttling, and store a brief information of what I understood, links that I visited, and throttling on Centrino (my processor) - I wouldn't have done that if I didn't search online for that message.

The objective is purely to improve my learning process and potentially read up on diverse aspects of systems. Additionally, I would also store the context in which I read something.
I wrote a [simple script in Perl](http://appolo85.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/logfile-inspector-for-linux-kernel-logs-to-track-online-resources-you-referred/) to do this along with more elaboration on my blog.

Is there a better way to go about this? Or do, you think that the effort is not worth it?
I look forward to suggestions!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds like a good one.  Ideally, people should be able to understand every line of their logs.

One resource that might come in handy is [logcheck](http://logcheck.org/).  It helps zero in both on what is most important as well as anomalies in your logs.

Comment: Hi Karl,
Thanks a lot for your reply!
I read the documentation-From what I can gather, the central aspect is that it matches messages to rules in the logcheck 'database'. I couldnt infer if we can add extra fields to the meta-data- like links visited,messages- I'll check it out!